# Jquery: What function should be given here[change or some other function]

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<select id="paymenttype">
<option value="">---Select---</option>
<option>100</option>
<option>200</option>
<option>300</option>
<option>400</option>
<option>500</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="check"   value="" readonly/>   
<input type="text" id="update"  value="" />
```

JS

```
$("#paymenttype").change(function(){
$("#check").val($('#paymenttype option:selected').text());
});

$("#check").change(function(){
alert("soul");
$("#update").val(0);
});
```

[Jsfiddle code example](http://jsfiddle.net/e6yEd/6/)

As shown in the code `$("#check").change(function()` it doesn't work? what function should i use in order to Jquery work? when there is change in the input text box check i am going to add? this is just an example

Comment: `change` will fire as soon as the element loses focus.

Comment: @JamesAllardice when there is change in the input text box check i am going to add? this is just an example

Comment: @Tomalak - I think the problem is that the `change` event bound to `#check` never fires (and it never will, because the element is `readonly`), so Richard D's answer is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to manually fire the change event when you set the value:

```
$("#paymenttype").change(function(){
   $("#check").val($('#paymenttype option:selected').text()).change(); // <-- HERE
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/e6yEd/7/

You could add a tiny plugin so you can set the value and fire the change event at the same time in a single call.

This way you just call `$("#check").changeVal($('#paymenttype option:selected').text());`:

```
(function($) { 
    $.fn.changeVal = function(value) {
        return this.val(value).change();       
    };
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/e6yEd/11/

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the trigger

```
$("#paymenttype").change(function(){
       $("#check").val($('#paymenttype option:selected').text()).change();
    });
```

note the `.change()` at the end of the second line

Answer (score 0):

Use [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function for run change() handler on '#check'
http://jsfiddle.net/fliptheweb/e6yEd/8/